# using ffmpeg instead of avconv

Tags: ffmpeg, avconv

i have 2 bash scripts wich i am trying to use which require avconv

when i run the scripts i get the error

```
bash: avconv: command not found
```

but since i dont know where to find avconv in either pacman or cower i was wandering if i could change the scripts to use ffmpeg instead

here are my scripts

stream.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
avconv -re -v error -fflags +genpts -i "$1" -c copy -f mpegts pipe:1
```

livestreamer.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
livestreamer -O "$1" best | avconv -re -v error -fflags +genpts -i pipe:0 -bsf h264_mp4toannexb -vcodec libx264 -acodec ac3 -f mpegts pipe:1
```

Comment: just a quick comment to explain that $1 is the url of the video

Comment: avconv is just a fork of ffmpeg, so you should be able to just change avconv -> ffmpeg and be fine.

Comment: Take a look at the docs for ffmpeg and see if the command line options still line up correctly. avconv forked back in 2011, and there's a chance that their command line options have diverged.